# Find the smallest two-digit number that has exactly 7 composite factors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I assumed N to be of type $p_1^a * p_2^b * p_3^c ......$ (k terms) where $p_1, p_2,....$ are all prime numbers

I know total factors would be $(a+1)*(b+1)*(c+1).....$(k terms), of which there will be '1' as non composite and 'k' as the count of prime numbers which we will have to subtract from the total factors thus the equation would turn out to be

$(a+1)*(b+1)*(c+1)..... - (1+k)= 7$

$(a+1)*(b+1)*(c+1)*....=8+k$

how to solve this further ? is there any better approach for this problem ?

Comment: I mean, $2^8=256$ is an option.  Beyond that, just search.  I'd look at $2^a3^b$.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you only wanted $2$ digit examples.  That makes the search even more trivial.

Comment: If $~n = p^a \times q^b ~: ~p,q~$ primes, then you need $~(a+1) \times (b+1) = 7 +3 = 10,~$ since all of the factors will be composite, except the elements in $~\{1,p,q\}.$

Answer (score 1):

The number of composite divisors equals the number of factors minus the number of distinct prime factors.

7 composite factors:

8 factors, 1 prime. a^7.
9 factors, 2 primes. a^2 b^2.
10 factors, 3 primes not possible.
11 factors, 4 primes not possible.

Comment: You wrote "The number of composite divisors equals the number of factors minus the number of distinct prime factors". However, $1$ is not usually considered to be either prime or composite, so the number of composite divisors is the number of factors minus one more than the number of distinct prime factors, as the OP has also acknowledged in their question's equation of $(a+1)*(b+1)*(c+1)..... - (1+k)= 7$.

Answer (score 1):

Might help to break it up into cases of number of prime factors.

For one prime factor: $p^a$ has $a+1$ factors, two of which are not composite. So we need to solve $a-1=7\implies a=8$.The smallest eighth power greater than 1 is 256, which is to large. So N has  more than 1 prime factor.

2 prime factors: $N=p_1^ap_2^b$. Number of composite factors is $(a+1)(b+1)-3=7\implies (a+1)(b+1)=10 $. The number 10 can be expressed as the product of two numbers in two ways, up to order of factors, $10=1\cdot 10$ and $10=2\cdot 5$. These expressions can be mapped to values for $a$ and $b$. 10 can't be one of the factors since $2^{10}=1024$ is too big. Let $a=4$ and $b=1$. We minimize $p_1^4p_2$ if we let $p_1=2$ and $p_2=3$. All combined this means N=48.

3 prime factors: $N=p_1^ap_2^bp_3^c$. $C.F.=(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)-4=7\implies (a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=11$. Since 11 is prime, 2 of the three factors must be 1, but this contradicts having 3 prime factors.

4 prime factors: $N=p_1^ap_2^bp_3^cp_4^d$. $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)=12$. Again, a,b,c and d can't be zero, and must be integers, so the minimum value on the left is 16>12. We have a contradiction.

This is the case for any larger number of prime factors.

So the only answer is N=48.

Comment: FYI, this is basically the way I approached solving the problem. However, I instead noted that any $n$ with $4$ or more prime factors would have $n\ge 2(3)(5)(7) = 210$, so it will always be too large.

Answer (score 0):

Let's work our way up:

n=1: $4=2^2$ (4); must be a square of a prime

n=2: $8=2^3$ (4,8); any product of 2 primes

n=3: $12=2^2 *3$ (12,6,4) [ $16=2^4$ (4,8,16)  ] [$30=2*3*5$ (6,10,15)]; any quartic of a prime, product of 3 unique primes or $p^2*q$ unique primes.

n = 5: $24 = 2^3*3$  (4,8,6,12,24)

n=6: $2^2*3^2 = 36$ (4,6,9,12,18,36)

n=7: $2^8$ (4,8,16,32,64,128, 256). so $p^8$ has 7 composite factors, but maybe there is some smaller number... something like
n= 8: $2^2*3*5=60$ has comp factors (4,6,10,15,12,20,30,60)
$2^2*3^2*5$ has comp factors (4,9,10,40,90,180,18,36... too many)
$2*3*5*7$ has comp factors (6,10,14,15,21,35,105, 210) .

In summary:

multiplying n unique primes gives #composite factors = (0,1,4,8)

$2^n$ has # composite factors = (n-1)

$2^2*p_1*...*p_n$ unique primes gives # composite factors = (2,8)

$2^3*3$ unique primes gives # composite factors = (5)

$2^2*3^2$ gives 6 composite factors.

$2^2*3^2*5$ gives more than 7 composite factors.

$2^4 *3$ gives 7 composite factors. Found it!

Comment: Note that as [user2661923's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4659088/find-the-smallest-two-digit-number-that-has-exactly-7-composite-factors#comment9841091_4659088) indicates, another solution would be $n=p^{a}\times q^{b}$ where $(a+1)\times(b+1)=10$. There's a solution using this which meets the OP question's requirement that it be $2$ digits long, instead of your answer's $2^{8}=256$ which is $3$ digits long.

Comment: $48$ is the answer.

Comment: @Mark You're incorrect since $n=2^{4}\times 3^{1}=48$ satisfies the requirements. In particular, it has a total of $(4+1)\times(1+1)=10$ factors, with all of them being composite except for $1$, $2$ and $3$, so there are $10 - 3 = 7$ composite factors. Note that $n=2^{4}\times 5^{1}=80$ is another $2$ digit number which satisfies the requirements, but it's not the smallest one.

Comment: ahh thanks. I got it now. I read $(a+1) + (b+1) = 10$ which is wrong, but it says times.